# Javascript highlighter in editable code

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have a highlighter made in JavaScript which change some word's color multiple times.

```
<div id="code" contenteditable="true">
 hello world hello world
</div>
```

I want to have an outuput as : " **Hello** world **Hello** world "

How can I change the color of both "hello" using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you elaborate please.

Comment: You can split the contents by " ", and then compare word to 'hello', and if you get a match, replace it for example with span-tag & color class. Then just gather new content from the array. But, this will have many and many different edge-cases that you need to take in count. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/680328/)

Comment: use `execCommand` simply.

Comment: @ShashankVivek does it still have compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this following code, you can write a function to find the words and replace them with a colorful element (e.g  or  & ...)

```js
$(function(){

  // inquire element for run the function
  var elem = $('#code');
  
  // call highlighter method with the word and elemnet
  highlighter('hello', elem);  
  
});

function highlighter(word, elem){
  // get inner html from passed element
  var html = elem.html();

  // define a new regex for replacing the word on specified element
  var reg = new RegExp(word,"g");
    
  // replace all found words with a new wrapped word
  html = html.replace(reg, "<span class='highlight'>" + word +"</span>");
  
  // set the specified element with new html
  elem.html(html);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="code" contenteditable="true">
 hello world hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Nice, it works! I think this i want i want! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your text to get each individual word, and then add each one in different 'span' tags which will have a 'fontWeight' property set to 'bold' if the word is 'hello'.

Here's an example:

```
var div = document.getElementById("code");
var text = div.innerText;
div.innerText = '';
text.split(' ').forEach(x => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = x + ' ';
  if(x == 'hello')
    span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  div.appendChild(span);
})
```

Try out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msf3o02a/20/)

Comment: As i see it works, but i don't know why, if i put your code inside a function and i call this function, code not works, can you share me how you do it inside a function? Thanks

Comment: I updated the fiddle. The text will only highlight if you click on the text now